# What's the song when Shiro is dying in the main chapel?

Tags: music, ninja-resurrection

In *Ninja Resurrection: The Revenge of Jubei* (the 1st OVA), there's a song playing near the end when Shiro is dying in the main chapel while being pleasured (reference on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNnR1gJEYws), **potentially NSFW**).

What's the name of the song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "Banner-Seal of Heterodoxy: The Son of Deus", the 4th track from "Ninja Resurrection (Original Soundtrack)". The preview of the OST can be listened on [AllMusic](https://www.allmusic.com/album/ninja-resurrection-original-soundtrack-mw0000514419).

According to the [OP's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46586/whats-the-name-of-this-song-played-in-this-scene-of-the-ova-ninja-ninja-resurre#comment60726_46597),

> it's the 4th song from the link you mentioned! Banner-Seal of Heterodoxy: The Son of Deus.

Comment: Hey bro, it's the 4th song from the link you mentioned!   
Banner-Seal of Heterodoxy: The Son of Deus. Thx :)